# What DNS settings to point domain2.com to sitename.example.com?

Tags: dns

I have a website at sitename.example.com.

What DNS settings do I use if I want domain2.com to point at it, without having to point directly at the IP address?

(Apparently it has to use CNAMEs rather that A Records because A Records require an IP address, I think?)

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record